# FileStream.EndWrite throws an exception (.NET)

Tags: .net, filestream

I'm trying to implement the progress notification mechanism when copying files.
I'm doing this in the following way:

1. I create two FileStreams - for reading and writing
2. Call the **BeginRead** passing to it a **ReadCallback** and a structure containing the reading stream and the array to fill with the data read from a file.
3. In the **ReadCallback** I call the **EndRead** method and call the **BeginWrite** method on the file stream used for writing passing to it a **WriteCallback** and a structure containing the stream (used for writing) and the array to write (the same as with the reading part).
4. When I call the **EndWrite** in the **WriteCallback** passing to it the asyncResult it throws an *ArgumentException: Either the IAsyncResult object did not come from the corresponding async method on this type, or EndRead was called multiple times with the same IAsyncResult*

Please help to resolve this.

**Update** Source code:

```
private void StartAsyncCopying()
{
    var sourceFileInfo = new FileInfo(Source);
    if (!sourceFileInfo.Exists)
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.",
            Source);
    }
    m_sourceLength = sourceFileInfo.Length;
    m_readerStream = new FileStream(Source, FileMode.Open);
    m_writerStream = new FileStream(Target, FileMode.Create);
    m_queueBuffer = new Queue<byte[]>(DefaultQueueBufferSize);
    m_queueBufferLock = new object();

    ProgressRead();
}

private void ProgressRead()
{
    var readerChunck = new byte[DefaultChunckSize];
    var streamChunck = new StreamChunck(readerChunck, m_readerStream);
    m_readerStream.BeginRead(streamChunck.Chunck,
        0,
        streamChunck.Chunck.Length,
        ReadCallback,
        streamChunck);
}


private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    var streamChunck = asyncResult.AsyncState as StreamChunck;
    var numberOfBytesRead = streamChunck.Stream.EndRead(asyncResult);

    m_readerOffset += numberOfBytesRead;

    ProgressWrite(streamChunck.Chunck);
}

private void ProgressWrite(byte[] chunck)
{
    var streamChunck = new StreamChunck(chunck, m_writerStream);
    m_writerAsyncResult = m_writerStream.BeginWrite(streamChunck.Chunck,
        0,
        streamChunck.Chunck.Length,
        WriteCallback,
        streamChunck);
}

private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    var streamChunck = asyncResult.AsyncState as StreamChunck;
    var numberOfBytesWritten = streamChunck.Stream.EndRead(asyncResult);
    m_writerOffset += numberOfBytesWritten;

    var progressChangedEventArgs = new CopyProgressChangedEventArgs(m_operationDescription,
        m_sourceLength,
        m_writerOffset);
    OnCopyProgressChanged(progressChangedEventArgs);

    if (m_writerOffset == m_sourceLength)
    {
        var copyCompletedEventArgs = new CopyCompletedEventArgs(m_operationDescription, null);
        OnCopyCompleted(copyCompletedEventArgs);
    }
    else
    {
        ProgressRead();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code please?

Comment: `EndRead` instead of `EndWrite` in `WriteCallback`, I've amended my answer.

Comment: Shame on me!
Adam thanks a lot for your precious time spent on my stupid question

Comment: Not stupid at all - sometimes we cannot see the wood for the trees - happens to everyone.  On a related note, picnic error means "Problem In Chair, Not In Computer" :-) happy coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `BeginXXX` you are likely given an `IAsyncResult` object, to call `EndXXX` you need to pass this `IAsyncResult` reference into the method.  If you have used the same object from the Read and passed that into the Write, it will not work - in your scenario there will be two separate `IAsyncResult` objects.

When I do this I keep a reference to the returned `IAsyncResult` as a local class variable (if using callbacks).  When I call `EndXXX` I provide this local reference (gained from my initial `BeginXXX`) and null it afterwards to signify it can be reused.

**Update 2:** looking at your code, what should be `EndWrite` in `WriteCallback` is actually an `EndRead`, picnic error :-)

**Update 1:** the following works fine for me...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
    class Program
    {
        static FileStream fs = null;
        static MemoryStream ms = null;
        static byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            fs = new FileStream("theFile", FileMode.Open);
            fs.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 512, new AsyncCallback(ReadFinished), null);

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void ReadFinished(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            fs.EndRead(res);
            fs.Dispose();

            ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, 512, new AsyncCallback(WriteFinished), null);
        }

        static void WriteFinished(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            ms.EndWrite(res);
            ms.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm passing a callback to the BeginWrite method and don't get an IAsyncResult object from it. The callback has the signature:
private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult) and operates on asyncResult passed to it. (In my Reading pair (BeginRead - ReadCallback it works fine).

Comment: Adam, thank you for the answer
I've just tried it - stored the reference returned by the BeginWrite and used it in the callback instead of passed as an argument.
The same exception is thrown again.

Comment: `BeginWrite` on a `Stream` returns `IAsyncResult`. However, I forgot the callback signature contained this, so its moot anyway - you don't need to use the returned reference.

Comment: @Serge if this is the case, then you have a logic bug somewhere - though I'd need to see the code for that.  Try the sample code I provided, and substitute your own file in.

Comment: ConsoleApplicetion14?  That's a lot of default projects in your project folder ;)

Comment: @Jesse lol that doesn't include all the WinForms ones either!

Answer (score 2):

You've got the following:

```
private void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    var streamChunck = asyncResult.AsyncState as StreamChunck;
    var numberOfBytesWritten = streamChunck.Stream.EndRead(asyncResult);
                                                   ^^^^^^^
```

but you are writing. Shouldn't you be calling `EndWrite`? Or am I missing something really obvious?

There's also a `ProgressRead();` in that method too.

Comment: Yes, there should be EndWrite
Thank you, ChrisF